# How can I set two rgb color codes for a backgroundColor in react-native

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

I need to set two rgb color codes in my app. How can I give two combination of background color in react-native

```
color:{
   backgroundColor: 'rgb 00 d0 njd', 'rgb 0090 j099'
}
```

Comment: You mean gradient type ?

Comment: do you mean gradient?

Comment: Please update your question with more information regarding what you want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can use **Gradient** for combine two RGB Color codes.